# Unable to login in to aspx website with selenium in python

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, authentication, python-3.4

I am trying to login into an aspx website.
**code:**

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
driver.get("https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("SchSel$txtUserName")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("Username")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
password = driver.find_element_by_name("SchSel$txtPassword")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.get("https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/WebApp/Index.aspx")
assert "Welcome" in driver.page_source
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

But I could not login.Are there any special parameters or something that has to be included so as to login?

Comment: What do you mean could not login?? And why are you using `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`??

Comment: keys.RETURN returns the username and password

Comment: What do you mean?? Sorry but I didn't understand???

Comment: Are you able to enter value on text field??

Comment: yes here is the site https://nucleus.niituniversity,in

Comment: You aren't clicking any login button here..why??

Comment: I thought keys.return does that.Isn't it?